# How to download BLOB file in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, blob

I have an Ionic app, i want to download a file in EXCEL format and the BLOB object looks like this :-

```
data: Blob(36199)
size: 36199
type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

How to download such Blob files? I have read about Cordova File plugin but haven't got any way to implement it for downloading Blob files.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Where is the blob located? Do you want to download it from external site?

Comment: That is a Devextreme Grid Control. I don't have any URL for this blob, i just have this data object. 
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onFileSaving this is the link to it.